# Confusing Exercise in Hilton/Stammbach's *A Course in Homological Algebra*

Tags: general-topology, category-theory, monomorphisms

An exercise in Hilton/Stammbach's book begins: "Show that $j : X_0 \to X$ in $\mathfrak{T}$ [the category of topological spaces and continuous maps] is a homeomorphism of $X_0$ *into* $X$ if and only if it is a monomorphism". I have a couple questions about this:

(1) By "homeomorphism into" do they mean "topological embedding"? This is an old book so I wouldn't be surprised if terminology has changed since the time it was written.

(2) I already showed in an earlier exercise that the monomorphisms in $\mathfrak{T}$ are the injective continuous maps, not the topological embeddings, contrary to what's being asked of me here. Am I misreading the question?

Comment: I'm not sure what they mean. You're right that the monos are the continuous injections. To me "homeomorphism into" sounds like it should be a homeomorphism betwen $X_0$ and $j[X_0]$, but this does not need to be the case for general monos. In fact, the inclusions which correspond to subspace topologies are exactly the [regular monos](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/regular+monomorphism). I would probably skip the exercise, satisfied you know what's going on, and carry on with your day (maybe showing that regular monos are the subspaces instead, as a treat :P )

Comment: That is an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, I was just misreading the sentence structure. The full sentence is "Show that $j : X_0 \to X$ is a homeomorphism of $X_0$ into $X$ [topological embedding] if and only if it is a monomorphism *and* for any $f : Y \to X$ in $\mathfrak{T}$, a factorization $U(j)g_0 = U(f)$ in $\mathfrak{S}$ [the category of sets] implies $jf_0 = f$ in $\mathfrak{T}$ with $g_0 = U(f_0)$." It's meant to be read "Show (P iff (Q and R))", but I mistakenly read it as "(Show (P iff Q)) and (Show R)".